# How to handle large file processing through AJAX and express

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

I'm uploading a PDF file using AJAX and express and sending the data to external REST API for some file processing.

Whenever I upload more than 3MB file I will get an error in AJAX before the REST API response. 
I get correct results from the external REST API, but processing takes more time so AJAX is not receiving the success msg.

How do I handle this?

Tried with AXIOS and other promise handler but same result

module.exports = (req, res) =>
 {

```
   var pdf = [],
    form = new formidable.IncomingForm(),
    pdfFile,
    dirname = process.cwd();


form.multiples = false;
// Upload directory for the images
form.uploadDir = path.join(dirname, 'tmp_uploads');
form.on('file', function(name, file) {
    let token;
    console.log('FORM ON')
    if (req.cookies.userData.token) {
        token = req.cookies.userData.token;

        let buffer = null,
            type = null,
            filename = '',
            renameFile = '';
        // Read a chunk of the file.
        buffer = readChunk.sync(file.path, 0, 262);
        // filename = Date.now() + '-' + file.name;
        filename = file.name;
        renameFile = path.join(dirname, 'uploads/' + filename);
        fs.rename(file.path, renameFile, function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('renamed complete');
            pdfFile = path.join(dirname, 'uploads/' + filename);
            let readFileStream = fs.createReadStream(pdfFile),
                data = '',
                formData = {};

            formData = {
                name: filename,
                my_file: readFileStream,
                Width: 1024,
                Height: 768
            };
            function postData() {
                // Setting URL and headers for request
                var options = {
                    url: EXTERNALURL,
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization": 'bearer ' + token,
                        "content-type": "multipart/form-data"
                    },
                    formData: formData
                };
                // Return new promise 
                return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    // Do async job
                    request.post(options, function(err, resp, body) {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(err);
                        } else {
                            resolve(body);
                        }
                    })
                })
            }

            function getData(url) {

                // Return new promise 
                return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    // Do async job
                    request.get({ url: url, encoding: null }, function(err, resp, body) {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(err);
                        } else {
                            resolve(body);
                        }
                    })
                })
            }
            var errHandler = function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }

            var filePath;

            function main() {

                var dataPromise = postData();
                // Get user details after that get followers from URL
                dataPromise.then(JSON.parse, errHandler)
                    .then(function(result) {
                        fData = result;
                        var fileName = fData.Id,
                            file_url = fData.PresentationZipUrl;
                        filePath = path.join(dirname, fData.HtmlPath);
                        // Do one more async operation here
                        var downloadPromise = getData(file_url).then();
                        return downloadPromise;
                    }, errHandler)
                    .then(function(data) {
                        //console.log(data);
                        var zip = new AdmZip(data);
                        if (!fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
                            fs.mkdirSync(filePath);
                            zip.extractAllTo(filePath, true);

                        }

                    }, errHandler)
                    .then(function(data) {
                        console.log('Done');
                        res.status(200).json({ 'status': "success" });
                    }, errHandler);
            }
            // console.log('before');
            main();

        }); // END RENAME FILE

    } else { // 
        console.log('ERROR')
        res.redirect('/');
    }


});

form.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('Error occurred during processing - ' + err);
});

// Invoked when all the fields have been processed.
form.on('end', function() {
    console.log('All the request fields have been processed.');
});

// Parse the incoming form fields.
form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {})}
```

AJAX: 
   `$`.ajax({

```
enter code here
url: '/presentation/uploadFiles',
method: 'post',
data: formData,
processData: false,
contentType: false,
timeout: 0}).done(function(d) {

console.log(d);
if (d.status == 'success') {
    location.reload()
}}).fail(function(e, t) {

console.log(e);
console.log(t)})
```

.always(function() {
});

Comment: Why do you set the AJAX timeout param to 0? Try to set it to 10000 (10 seconds) or the time you consider appropriate

Comment: If I give that it will give me timeout error. Because processing will take more than that.

Comment: So set the time you consider appropriate, as I said